# Is it possible to get an email notification when I close an Azure Sentinel incident?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

I want to send out an email when I close an incident in azure sentinel - or on any update I make like changing the severity or assignation - is this possible or can someone suggest any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,You can get alerts to your email using azure Monitor. Here is Screenshot of how it worked for me.

[image]

REFERENCES:

1. [Closing an Incident in Azure Sentinel and Dismissing an Alert in Azure Security Center - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-security-center/closing-an-incident-in-azure-sentinel-and-dismissing-an-alert-in/ba-p/1180208)
2. [Azure Monitor Logs reference - SecurityIncident | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/securityincident)
3. [Sentinel Email Notification Logic App – Azure Cloud & AI Domain Blog (azurecloudai.blog)](https://azurecloudai.blog/2020/09/23/sentinel-email-notification-logic-app/)